# Plotting stacked plot from grouped pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame which looks as given below.First, I wanted the count of each status in each date. For example number of  'COMPLETED' in 2017-11-02 is 2.I want a stack plot of such.

```
                   status              start_time                end_time  \
0             COMPLETED 2017-11-01 19:58:54.726 2017-11-01 20:01:05.414   
1             COMPLETED 2017-11-02 19:43:04.000 2017-11-02 19:47:54.877   
2     ABANDONED_BY_USER 2017-11-03 23:36:19.059 2017-11-03 23:36:41.045   
3  ABANDONED_BY_TIMEOUT 2017-10-31 17:02:38.689 2017-10-31 17:12:38.844   
4             COMPLETED 2017-11-02 19:35:33.192 2017-11-02 19:42:51.074
```

Here is the csv for the dataframe:

```
status,start_time,end_time
COMPLETED,2017-11-01 19:58:54.726,2017-11-01 20:01:05.414
COMPLETED,2017-11-02 19:43:04.000,2017-11-02 19:47:54.877
ABANDONED_BY_USER,2017-11-03 23:36:19.059,2017-11-03 23:36:41.045
ABANDONED_BY_TIMEOUT,2017-10-31 17:02:38.689,2017-10-31 17:12:38.844
COMPLETED,2017-11-02 19:35:33.192,2017-11-02 19:42:51.074
ABANDONED_BY_TIMEOUT,2017-11-02 19:35:33.192,2017-11-02 19:42:51.074
```

To achieve this:

```
df_['status'].astype('category')
df_ = df_.set_index('start_time')
grouped = df_.groupby('status')
color = {'COMPLETED':'green','ABANDONED_BY_TIMEOUT':'blue',"MISSED":'red',"ABANDONED_BY_USER":'yellow'}

for key_, group in grouped:
   print(key_)
   df_ = group.groupby(lambda x: x.date).count()
   print(df_)
   df_['status'].plot(label=key_,kind='bar',stacked=True,\
   color=color[key_],rot=90)
plt.show()
```

The output of the following is :

```
ABANDONED_BY_TIMEOUT
            status  end_time  
2017-10-31       1         1       
ABANDONED_BY_USER
            status  end_time  
2017-11-03       1         1            
COMPLETED
            status  end_time  
2017-11-01       1         1             
2017-11-02       2         2
```

[image: plot from above code]

The problem here as we can see it is taking into account only last two dates '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-02' instead of all the dates in all the categories.
How can I solve this problem?I am welcome to a whole new approach for stacked plot.Thanks in advance.

Comment: first post your full dataframe as csv in your question

Comment: there you go, edited with csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df_ = pd.read_csv('sam.csv')
df_['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_['start_time']).dt.date
df_ = df_.set_index('start_time')


grouped = pd.DataFrame(df_.groupby(['date', 'status']).size().reset_index(name="count")).pivot(columns='status', index='date', values='count')
print(grouped)
sns.set()

grouped.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

# g = grouped.plot(x='date', kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try restructuring `df_` with [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) instead:

```
color = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'red']
df_xtab = pd.crosstab(df_.start_time.dt.date, df_.status)
```

This `DataFrame` will look like:

```
status      ABANDONED_BY_TIMEOUT  ABANDONED_BY_USER  COMPLETED
start_time                                                    
2017-10-31                     1                  0          0
2017-11-01                     0                  0          1
2017-11-02                     1                  0          2
2017-11-03                     0                  1          0
```

and will be easier to plot.

```
df_xtab.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, color=color, rot=90)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use seaborn library [`barplot`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kGmw.png) with its hue

**code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df_ = pd.read_csv('sam.csv')
df_['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_['start_time']).dt.date
df_ = df_.set_index('start_time')

print(df_)

grouped = pd.DataFrame(df_.groupby(['date', 'status']).size().reset_index(name="count"))
print(grouped)

g = sns.barplot(x='date', y='count', hue='status', data=grouped)
plt.show()
```

**output:**
[image]

---

data:

```
status,start_time,end_time
COMPLETED,2017-11-01 19:58:54.726,2017-11-01 20:01:05.414
COMPLETED,2017-11-02 19:43:04.000,2017-11-02 19:47:54.877
ABANDONED_BY_USER,2017-11-03 23:36:19.059,2017-11-03 23:36:41.045
ABANDONED_BY_TIMEOUT,2017-10-31 17:02:38.689,2017-10-31 17:12:38.844
COMPLETED,2017-11-02 19:35:33.192,2017-11-02 19:42:51.074
ABANDONED_BY_TIMEOUT,2017-11-02 19:35:33.192,2017-11-02 19:42:51.074
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, I chaged the data a little bit so that it is easy to visualize stacked bar plot. I don't think your answer helps with that. Any solutions ?

Comment: it still does its job

Comment: whats the problem?,  i don't get it

Comment: for date 2017-11-02. I want a stacked bar plot instead of set of vertical bars